# The executing order gets incorrect in python threading, how to make it correct?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I would like to get data from a sensor, and put that record on the cloud service in the correct order.

It takes time to put record, so I try using threading method so that I can get data simultaneously (otherwise data would be gone while putting records)

Here is my dummy code.

```
import threading
import time

def putrecord(data_put):
    time.sleep(0.8) #it takes time to put record
    print(data_put[-1]) #sometimes unordered (ex. 9,29,19,...)

def main():
    data_put=[]
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.08) #getting data from a sensor
        data_put.append(i)
        if len(data_put)>=10: #every 10 records
            sub = threading.Thread(target=putrecord,args=(data_put,))
            sub.start()
            data_put=[]
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then somehow sometime, the order gets incorrect (it does not happen on the dummy code).
I have no confident idea why it happens, but I guess it happens when getting/putting data takes time longer than usual.
Is there any way to put record in the correct order in that case?

I hope to make myself understood.

Comment: How do you define "correct order"?  If you need predictable serial execution, then maybe you don't need threading.  There is always a chance that your thread will get to `data_put[-1]` before the main thread has stored anything in the list, which will fail.

Comment: Or queue the data and have the put thread query the queue, then put new data if present, sleep otherwise.

Comment: You should have a single thread for writing all the records.  It repeatedly reads from a queue and writes that record.  Your main() program then "fetches" items and puts them on the queue.  Since you only have a single process pushing items, it can't get out of order.  Note that multithreading queues have a get() method that waits until an item becomes available, so no sleeping is necessary.

Comment: Does `putrecord` have to process a fixed number of records each time or it's OK if it processes any number of records?

Comment: Thank you all for comments. Ive got to have a running thread wait until another one has finished as yall mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you get and put data can fail if a thread takes too long "putting a record". If it takes long enough, new data will arrive and a new thread will be created and started. This thread will "put" records concurrently with the older one, resulting in out of order data.

Moreover, you are not joining the threads you create. This results in a very small resource leak (it's equivalent to not closing a file), that probably does not matter (unless you program runs continuously for many years).

The most elegant way of implementing what you need is to use a queue, as @jarmod proposed in the comments. Nevertheless, you can use a simpler approach reusing your code.

If you need the data to be processed in chunks of fixed number of records (as in you example), you can keep those chunks on a list and start a thread only after the previous one has finished:

```py
import threading
import time

def putrecord(chunk):
    time.sleep(0.8) #it takes time to put record
    for data_put in chunk:
        print(data_put[-1])

def main():
    data=[]
    chunks = []
    sub = None
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.08) #getting data from a sensor
        data.append(i)
        if len(data) >= 10: #every 10 records
            chunks.append(data)
            data = []
            if sub and  not sub.is_alive():
                sub.join(0)
                sub = None
            if not sub:
                sub = threading.Thread(target=putrecord,args=(chunks,))
                sub.start()
                chunks = []
    if sub:
        sub.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you actually don't need to process the data in chunks, you can feed whatever data you got from the sensor since the previous thread was started:

```
import threading
import time

def putrecord(data_put):
    time.sleep(0.8) #it takes time to put record
    print(data_put, data_put[-1]) #sometimes unordered (ex. 9,29,19,...)

def main():
    data_put=[]
    # sub = threading.Thread(target=putrecord,args=(data_put,))
    sub = None
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.01) #getting data from a sensor
        data_put.append(i)
        if len(data_put) >= 10: #every 10 records
            if sub and  not sub.is_alive():
                sub.join(0)
                sub = None
            if not sub:
                sub = threading.Thread(target=putrecord,args=(data_put,))
                sub.start()
                data_put=[]
    if sub:
        sub.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please note that in both approaches you can miss the final data: you have to check if there was data waiting to be written and take care of it.